# Hashing a solr input field

Tags: security, solr

I would like to facilitate searching on a field that we cannot index or store in non hashed or encrypted form.  Is there a way to tell solr to hash (or encrypt) a speicfic field prior to comparing against the index?

Answer (score 5):

In a nutshell, I don't think it's easy, and it depends on what level of security you need.

As a generic, simple solution, you could store the whole index in an encrypted file system, e.g. [eCryptfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECryptfs) or [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) (see [difference between block-level encryption and fs-level encryption](http://ecryptfs.sourceforge.net/ecryptfs-faq.html#compare))

Depending on how you need to search in this field, if you can get away with just hashing the values then the solution would be purely client-side, i.e. hashing the value client-side, sending it to Solr and getting back the results.

Some years ago there was a [patch to enable field-level encryption in Lucene](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-737), but for some reason it was rejected. Still, maybe you can borrow some ideas from that patch...

Comment: Whoa! Why isn't it easy? You just said in your answer that you can hash the field before indexing it, then hash the search value on the client (Javascript) so that the client is submitting the hashed value. Seems pretty easy. But make sure that your hash uses a salt, and that it is not the same salt as is used where the data is stored in its home database.

Comment: @Michael: the client is generally NOT javascript (i.e. the browser), but the **client to Solr**, i.e. PHP, Ruby or whatever you're using to talk to Solr. Also, hashing like that will prevent many kinds of search.

Comment: If the SOLR client is PHP, Ruby or whatever, it is even easier to do the hashing. And I think the whole idea of hashing the data is to enable more kinds of search than you would get by NOT indexing that field.

Comment: @Michael: hashing *constrains* the kind of searches you can do. For example, you can't do ngrams.

Comment: @Mauricio, if you read the question you will see that they either want to or have to constrain the kind of searches that can be done. Given those constraints, they can still do some searches by having the client compute a hash and submit the search with the hash.

Comment: @Michael: I always read the questions before answering. The OP didn't mention any 'constrain', and he mentions both 'hashing' and 'encrypting' so I can't tell for sure which one he needs. Also, I did offer solutions including encrypting and hashing, just in case, so what are we discussing here?