# Encrypting the indexes in solr and Lucene

Tags: encryption, solr, lucene, indexing

I would like to know if there a way to encrypt the indexes in solr and Lucene?
As the content is hosted on AWS.

Comment: If you care that much about confidentiality, you should probably not use AWS at all and rather have your own cloud. Moreover, I am afraid that encrypting the index would kill performance.

Comment: Might be possible to encrypt certain sensitive fields, while leaving others decrypted

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915265/hashing-a-solr-input-field

Answer (score 0):

There's a [patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2228) for Lucene 3.1 that provides an encryption solution for Lucene indexes, using the AES encryption algorithm. You must have the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 6 Release Candidate which
you can get from java.sun.com.